# Freeing allocated space after deleting a node in a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am studying about linked list in a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132923726) for a university course. I have a problem with deleting a node in a linked list. The given structure for the list is

```
struct Node {
int item;
Node *next;
}
```

and in the part of the book I'm in,deleting a node using two pointers : prev, and cur (where cur points to the node to be deleted ) is being demonstrated.

After rerouting prev to the node after cur:

```
prev->next = cur->next;
```

We Proceed to free the memory used for the node in cur. My problem is with this part, the code used is:

```
cur->next = NULL;
delete cur;
cur = NULL;
```

Aren't the first and third line redundant ? or is there something I'm missing? since we delete cur as we do in the second line then we should not need to set cur->next= null first right?

In the book it gives an [explanation](http://s24.postimg.org/oesojygg3/Screenshot_from_2015_12_03_11_55_31.png), however it doesn't make much sense. Any help ?

Comment: Lots of books aren't very good, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Setting `cur` to null *might* be useful if you keep the pointer around for later. Otherwise not. Setting `next` to null is just useless.

Comment: It is redundant but as the book says, it's *defensive* - it's a habit that increases the chance that something bad will happen sooner rather than later if you do something you shouldn't (like, say, `*cur` or happen to have saved a copy of `cur` and later dereference a stale `next` pointer).

Comment: @molbdnilo: it is **not** defensive! Setting `cur->next` set a value whose access becomes undefined on the next line to start with. If anything should set the content of deleted memory, it would be a [debugging] `operator delete`. Whether setting `cur` to `NULL` is reasonable depends on whether it continues to be used or not. If it just a local variable which goes out of scope on the next line it is still pointless.

Comment: The nulling of `next` can be of help in debugging (one can see that a node that is assumed to be valid, has been destroyed). However, I would never do it. If one gets to the stage where such techniques have any value, then the code is beyond hope and should be scrapped.

Comment: What is the point of so-called 'defensive programming' if it caused so much FUD?  Same with the cargo-cult zeroing of buffers before reading stuff in to them in the next line.  Newbs look at such rubbish and are totally baffled.

Comment: @MartinJames And testing a socket for null immediately after `new Socket(...)`, and testing whether it's connected when it would have thrown an exception if it wasn't. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, yes, the first and third line are redundant